# Rails Heroku JavaScript problems

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have RoR app and 4 environments therein-development, test, production1, production2.
 And I have 2 Heroku servers for production.
I make some changes and push it on my servers. One of the servers I notice a strange work of JavaScript. In js-console I see many errors - "http://js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-248.min.js not fount", etc. On localy and another server this problem not happends.
I correctly configurate heroku config - define rails and rake env.
Before push I made -  RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile.
Where do I go please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
heroku config:set RAILS_ENV=production -a your-app-name
```

or whatever environment you want to set.